# Not able to fetch the image from database in django application

Tags: django

In my application, I am able to fetch all the other contents like name description but instead of using the all code correctly and all things may be clear the images are not loading.. please help [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl3Od.png)

Comment: Bibek, kindly add more details - you need to show your django models, settings. Are you able to see the images getting uploaded in django admin? Have you set up the media settings properly?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste the code in directly. Images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled to reproduce the problem, are hard to read on mobile devices, may be blocked by proxies or firewalls, and can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.  For more information, please see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<img src="/media/{{ dest.img.url }}">
```

Comment: Is it working now